# Why gulp cannot transpile scss file into css file?

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I am beginner for using gulp.

I am using Visual Studio Code Editor - version of 1.41.1.
My OS is Windows7.

I have already installed gulp with guidance on gulpjs.com. Refefrence link is here: https://gulpjs.com/.
However, when I typed command: gulp sass in visual studio code editor, my scss file was not converted into css file. And, editor displayed following message instead.

```
The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of  the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:5
+ gulp <<<<  sass
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gulp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I also checked the path in gulpfile.js. I think there's no problem with the path.
My gulpfile.js is following.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('project/src/sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('project/dist/css'));
});
```

Could you tell me why and how to fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you install gulp globally ?

Comment: Try this out.. `npm install gulp -g --latest`

Comment: @MihaiT I installed gulp globally. I used following command for installation.

npm install gulp-cli -g

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks for your suggestion. I tried but it still doesn't work. Editor displayed same message.

Comment: What command you are using to execute it ?

Comment: @rahulsharma Normally, we use gulp command to excute it. In my case, maybe there's something wrong when I installed gulp, thus I used command of run npm gulp to excute it. But, it didn't work today and I didn't know any reasons for that. Thus, after trying many ways, I decided to reinstall nodejs and gulp again. Fortunately, it worked. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have created this code for gulpJs 4.
it may Help you

run this command

```
npm install gulp-concat gulp-autoprefixer gulp-sass gulp-sass-glob node-sass --save-dev
```

use Sudo if you are using linux

```
    const { src, dest } = require("gulp");
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer");
const sass = require("gulp-sass");
const sassGlob = require("gulp-sass-glob");
sass.compiler = require("node-sass");



function css() {
    return src("src/css/*.css")
        .pipe(concat("style.css"))
        .pipe(sassGlob())
        .pipe(
            sass({
                outputStyle: "compressed" //expand or compact or compressed
            }).on("error", sass.logError)
        )
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                cascade: true
            })
        )
        .pipe(dest("build/css/"));
}


function scss() {
    return src('src/scss/style.scss') // import your all file in style.scss
        .pipe(sassGlob())
        .pipe(
            sass({
                outputStyle: 'compressed' // you can set "expand or compact or compressed" view 
            })
                .on('error', sass.logError)
        ).pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                cascade: true
            })
        ).pipe(dest('build/scss/'));
}

exports.css = css;
exports.scss= scss;
```